# Undefined length error

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error

```
let lCdata = component.get("v.lCdata");

console.log("listCustomerData size:::"+JSON.stringify(listCustomerData));
console.log("lCdata size:::"+lCdata.length);
console.log("lCdata size:::"+lCdata[0].orderLine.length);//throwing the error
```

debug:

> lCdata size::: [{"value":[{"accountName":"AI",
> "createdDate":"2020-09-14","orderLine":
> [{"batchName":"100","orderedQty":1}],"orderStatus":"Cancelled"} ]}]

Answer (score 0):

Access `orderLine` as `lCdata.value[0].orderLine` and its length as `lCdata.value[0].orderLine.length`

Comment: Arut, while adding an answer make sure you add an explanation of why your solution will work. just putting a possible answer will not help the asker.

Answer (score 0):

If you see, the JSON is part of arrays, so it shall be used as `lCdata[0].value[0].orderLine.length`. See the details below -

**JSON with proper syntax :**

```json
 [{
    "value": [{
        "accountName": "AI",
        "createdDate": "2020-09-14",
        "orderLine": [{
            "batchName": "100",
            "orderedQty": 1
        }],
        "orderStatus": "Cancelled"
    }]
 }]
```

I tried JSON from the debug and here it's how shall be used -

**Code to replicate the same :**

```js
let lCdata = JSON.parse( '[{"value":[{"accountName":"AI", "createdDate":"2020-09-14","orderLine": [{"batchName":"100","orderedQty":1}],"orderStatus":"Cancelled"} ]}]');

console.log(' Length of orderLine is ::: ' + lCdata[0].value[0].orderLine.length);
```